# Changing the origin location to the current location

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a google map in my MVC 5 project with origin location and destination location. I need the origin location to be changed to a set address and never change instead of typing the address every time i need to use it.

Its two text fields with origin location and destination location. The origin location i want it to be set to one physical address only.

the following is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head >
    <title>Place Autocomplete</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 10%;
        width:100%;
        padding-top: 800px;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 10%;
         width:100%;
       
   
      }
      .controls {
         
        margin-top: 10px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 32px;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }

      #origin-input,
      #destination-input {
       
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 200px;
      }

      #origin-input:focus,
      #destination-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      #mode-selector {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
      }

      #mode-selector label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <input id="origin-input" class="controls" type="text"
            value ="8 Parsia Lane, Tongaat, South Africa" >

    <input id="destination-input" class="controls" type="text"
           placeholder="Enter a destination location">

    <div id="mode-selector" class="controls">
        <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-walking" checked="checked">
        <label for="changemode-walking">Walking</label>

        <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-transit">
        <label for="changemode-transit">Transit</label>

        <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-driving">
        <label for="changemode-driving">Driving</label>
    </div>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          mapTypeControl: false,
          center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
          zoom: 13
        });

        new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);
      }

     // 
         
     
      function AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map) {
        this.map = map;
        this.originPlaceId = null;
        this.destinationPlaceId = null;
        this.travelMode = 'WALKING';
        var originInput = document.getElementById('origin-input');
        var destinationInput = document.getElementById('destination-input');
        var modeSelector = document.getElementById('mode-selector');
        this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        this.directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        var originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            originInput, {placeIdOnly: true});
        var destinationAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            destinationInput, {placeIdOnly: true});

        this.setupClickListener('changemode-walking', 'WALKING');
        this.setupClickListener('changemode-transit', 'TRANSIT');
        this.setupClickListener('changemode-driving', 'DRIVING');

        this.setupPlaceChangedListener(originAutocomplete, 'ORIG');
        this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete, 'DEST');

        this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(originInput);
        this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(destinationInput);
        this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(modeSelector);
      }

      // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
      // Autocomplete.
      AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupClickListener = function(id, mode) {
        var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
        var me = this;
        radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
          me.travelMode = mode;
          me.route();
        });
      };

      AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupPlaceChangedListener = function(autocomplete, mode) {
        var me = this;
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          if (!place.place_id) {
            window.alert("Please select an option from the dropdown list.");
            return;
          }
          if (mode === 'ORIG') {
            me.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
          } else {
            me.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
          }
          me.route();
        });

      };

      AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.route = function() {
        if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId) {
          return;
        }
        var me = this;

        this.directionsService.route({
          origin: {'placeId': this.originPlaceId},
          destination: {'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId},
          travelMode: this.travelMode
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            me.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      };

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAcXA5KHYBhOQPuV3ygleDCPu8w2BHq4OY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't you have the origin set to one address? `value ="8 Parsia Lane, Tongaat, South Africa"`

Comment: i do but it only selects that value when i click on the auto complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code as here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head >
<title>Place Autocomplete</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
   * element that contains the map. */
   #map {
    height: 80%;
  }
  /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  /* #map {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    padding-top: 800px;
  }

  html, body {
    height: 10%;
    width:100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  } */
  .controls {         
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }

  #origin-input,
  #destination-input {

    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-left: 12px;
    padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 200px;
  }

  #origin-input:focus,
  #destination-input:focus {
    border-color: #4d90fe;
  }

  #mode-selector {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4d90fe;
    margin-left: 12px;
    padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
  }

  #mode-selector label {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
  }

</style>

</head>
<body>
<header>
    <h2>This is my header</h2>
</header>
<input id="origin-input" class="controls" type="text"
        value ="Sydney, Australia" >

<input id="destination-input" class="controls" type="text"
       placeholder="Enter a destination location">

<div id="mode-selector" class="controls">
    <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-walking" checked="checked">
    <label for="changemode-walking">Walking</label>

    <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-transit">
    <label for="changemode-transit">Transit</label>

    <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-driving">
    <label for="changemode-driving">Driving</label>
</div>

<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
  // parameter when you first load the API. For example:


  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeControl: false,
      center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
      zoom: 13
    });

    new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);
  }

 // 


  function AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map) {
    this.map = map;
    this.originPlaceId = null;
    this.destinationPlaceId = null;
    this.travelMode = 'WALKING';
    var originInput = document.getElementById('origin-input');
    var destinationInput = document.getElementById('destination-input');
    var modeSelector = document.getElementById('mode-selector');
    this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    this.directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    // var originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    //     originInput, {placeIdOnly: true});
    var destinationAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        destinationInput, {placeIdOnly: true});

    this.setupClickListener('changemode-walking', 'WALKING');
    this.setupClickListener('changemode-transit', 'TRANSIT');
    this.setupClickListener('changemode-driving', 'DRIVING');

    // this.setupPlaceChangedListener(originAutocomplete, 'ORIG');
    this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete, 'DEST');

    this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(originInput);
    this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(destinationInput);
    this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(modeSelector);
  }

  // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
  // Autocomplete.
  AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupClickListener = function(id, mode) {
    var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
    var me = this;
    radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      me.travelMode = mode;
      me.route();
    });
  };

  AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupPlaceChangedListener = function(autocomplete, mode) {
    var me = this;
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (!place.place_id) {
        window.alert("Please select an option from the dropdown list.");
        return;
      }
      if (mode === 'ORIG') {
        me.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
      } else {
        me.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
      }
      me.route();
    });

  };

  AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.route = function() {
    //if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId) {
    if (!this.destinationPlaceId) {
      return;
    }
    var me = this;

    this.directionsService.route({
      origin: document.getElementById('origin-input').value,
      destination: {'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId},
      travelMode: this.travelMode
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        me.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  };

</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAcXA5KHYBhOQPuV3ygleDCPu8w2BHq4OY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

Comment: i tried that but i still have to click on the autocomplete for it to hold the value then i have to type in the destination address and then only it works

Comment: You can set the autocomplete to off as well. You only want the value of the origin input to be fixed right. So you will have to type in a destination address. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I found the issue. Your origin input is triggered by autocomplete. So instead you just need to get the value from the origin input and set it in the directionsService call. I have updated the answer.

Comment: i just tried this and i still have to click on the autocomplete :(. Thanks for the help though. I really appreciate it

Comment: Definitely got it working now. Just replace your code with what I sent in answer. Or just replace `if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId) {` with `if (!this.destinationPlaceId) {`

Comment: i need one more favor. My Style sheet is messing with me and the top of the map is stuck to the header i need to bring the map more down because i need to put a header tag and stuff above that. Can anyone help me please

Comment: its displaying where the map is above my headers and stuff

Comment: What do you mean? I have added a header tag. And it is displaying above the map as it should. Could you clarify the question and what you are trying to do?